# Как максимально оптимизировать PostgreSQL запрос используя только индексы?

Tags: sql, postgresql, оптимизация, индексы

[сслыка на базу данных](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/dvdrental.zip)

[ER Model](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-getting-started/postgresql-sample-database/)

popular movies year by year

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT title, release_year
FROM film f1
WHERE f1.rental_rate > (SELECT AVG(f2.rental_rate) FROM film f2 WHERE
f1.release_year = f2.release_year);
```

Попробовал кучу индексов, никак не получается оптимизировать агрегатную функцию. (Менять сам запрос нельзя)

"Seq Scan on film f1  (cost=0.00..69079.00 rows=333 width=19) (actual time=1.349..282.051 rows=659 loops=1)"
"  Filter: (rental_rate > (SubPlan 1))"
"  Rows Removed by Filter: 341"
"  SubPlan 1"
"    ->  Aggregate  (cost=69.00..69.01 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.281..0.281 rows=1 loops=1000)"
"          ->  Seq Scan on film f2  (cost=0.00..66.50 rows=1000 width=6) (actual time=0.001..0.149 rows=1000 loops=1000)"
"                Filter: ((f1.release_year)::integer = (release_year)::integer)"
"Planning Time: 0.982 ms"
"Execution Time: 282.187 ms"

Comment: Пробовать наугад - так себе занятие. Покажите результат `explain (analyze, buffers) ... ` и добавьте в текст вопроса схему таблицы

Comment: сделайте покрывающий индекс по используемым полям и этот расчет среднего уберите в джойн внутри которого группировка по годам

Comment: Для оптимизации агрегатных функций больше подходит колоночный индекс. Если всё таки колоночный нельзя, то покрывающий индекс